# Cordova ubuntu desktop application issue

Tags: cordova, ubuntu

guys.

I'm going to develop cordova app for pc with ubuntu installed.

But after I installed and ran default test app, "sudo cordova run ubuntu" successfully built and launched something (according to terminal), but nothing happened, no app appeared, icon etc. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was to use a more recent version of Ubuntu.

I ran into the same issue when I tried following the guide at https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ubuntu/ on Ubuntu 14.04.  Turns out the Cordova "Ubuntu" platform requires Ubuntu.Components 1.1.  The version of Ubuntu.Components on my Ubuntu 14.04 was too low.

"cordova run ubuntu" worked fine for me on Ubuntu 16.04.